# Nextjs App Router Set Global Axios Instance Bearer Token

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, next.js, axios

I have a turborepo with two nextjs apps (web and admin) along with a shared packages directory. In this directory I want to create a shared axios instance for both apps to use. How can I set the authorization header in the axios instance?

For example:

#### /apps/web/middleware.ts

```
import { getToken } from "next-auth/jwt";
import { withAuth } from "next-auth/middleware";
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";

export default withAuth(
  async function middleware(req) {
    const token = await getToken({ req, secret: process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET });

    const requestHeaders = new Headers(req.headers);

    requestHeaders.set('authorization', `Bearer ${token["idToken"]}`);

    return NextResponse.next({
      request: {
        headers: requestHeaders,
      },
    });

  },
  {
    callbacks: {
      authorized: ({ token }) => {
        if (token) {
          return true;
        }
        return false;
      }
    },
  }
);

export const config = { matcher: ["/"] };
```

This code sets the correct bearer token for each subsequent request. The problem is my axios instance is defined in

#### /packages/app/lib/axios.ts

```
import axios from "axios";
import { headers } from "next/headers";

const headersInstance = headers();
const authorization = headersInstance.get('authorization');

export const axiosInstance = axios.create({
    baseURL: "http://localhost:7112/api/",
    timeout: 1000,
    headers: { authorization } ===> this does not work, header is null
});
```

How can I get the authorization header in the instance without having to set it for each call?